# Laravel collection retrieve variable result from each function

Tags: php, eloquent, scope, laravel-5.6, laravel-collection

I retrieve a laravel collection from a database on which I want to update certain values based on three calculations.  But before I do the calculations I first check if all the relevant collection items is not null.  I can check if they are null but for some reason cannot rerieve an error variable that has Controller function scope to tell a user that a variable has not been set.

```php
$error_arr = [];
$calculation = FertilApp::calculation($product, $farm, $agent);
$calculation->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if ($item->ha === null) {
        $error_arr[] = 'Prices has been updated';
        $error_arr[] = 'But no calculation has been done, please update following block:' . $item->block;
        return false;
     }
});
```

The variable `$error_arr` returns an empty array even though I know the `ha` key is `null`.
The alternative is to use a normal `foreach()` loop. I have tried it and it  works, but I really want to know why this is not working.

Can someone please help to give me a clue to why this collection `each()` method is denying my variable access to values from outside  the collection method?

EDIT:  If I try to pass my variable as a parameter I get the following error message `Cannot use a scalar value as an array`.

**Laravel version: 5.6.39**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `global` statement:

```
$calculation->each(function ($item, $key) {
   global $error_arr;
```

`$error_arr` is empty in your code, because it doesn't exist in the scope of the callback `function` of your `each` method. Unlike other languages – like JavaScript – variables outside a function aren't accessible by default inside the function. See [PHP's documentation on variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for details.

Comment: Thanks your solution works.  I also had to add `global $error_arr` in front of the variable declaration of my Controller function.  This was in the comment section in your link.  This is due to the fact that `$calculation->each(function ($item, $key) {` is a child function of my Controller function.