# Access variable outside laravel closure function

Tags: php, laravel, closures

I'm using Laravel 8 and PHP 8.

I have a variable that I defined in the global scope and assigned `null` value.

I am using laravel's collection's `each` function to iterate over each element. Inside this closure I have another closure which is collection's `filter` function. I am assigning the output of filter `function` into global variable and it is working but inside the closure of `each` function only. (checked using xdebug)

Outside the closure the variable becomes `null` again even though I passed the variable inside closure using `use()` function but still it's not working.

```
$filtered = null;

$product->each(function ($price) use($coupons, $filtered) {

    $filtered = $coupons->filter(function ($coupon) use($price) {
        if (!empty($price->iso_code)) {
            if ($coupon->iso_code = $price->iso_code) {
                $a = $price->currency_code;
                $b = $coupon->currency_code;
                return $a == $b;
            }
        }
        return $price->currency_code = $coupon->currency_code;
    });

});

return $filtered; //null
```

I have referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367075/4494813) & [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530159/4494813) but no luck.

Can someone please guide me how can I assign the output of `filter` function to global variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the change effect outside of closure, you need to use reference, like this

[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

```
$filtered = null;

$product->each(function ($price) use($coupons, &$filtered) {

    $filtered = $coupons->filter(function ($coupon) use($price) {
        if (!empty($price->iso_code)) {
            if ($coupon->iso_code = $price->iso_code) {
                $a = $price->currency_code;
                $b = $coupon->currency_code;
                return $a == $b;
            }
        }
        return $price->currency_code = $coupon->currency_code;
    });

});

return $filtered;
```

Comment: I tried but looks I have to wait 6 more minutes

Comment: Okay so please do it after that limit, Thanks in advance.